# How to get the last digit of a long?

Tags: java

I am trying to write Java code to obtain the last digit of a long (i.e. the rightmost digit).

If I were trying to obtain the last element of a string, I would use the substring() method.

What is the alternative or equivalent way when getting the last digit of a long?

Comment: The answer in that other question doesn't work for negative numbers :p

Comment: Well are you looking for % operator in general programming languages ?

Answer (score 15):

You can do

```
long digit = Math.abs(number%10);
```